# IE9 : Arrow Keys not working in text area field in popups

Tags: popup, internet-explorer-9, textarea, arrow-keys

We are just testing our application on IE9 and I found an issue regarding the arrow keys behaviour in text area in popup window.

Two arrow keys are not working fine:

1) Left arrow key - When we enter some multiline text in the text field and try to move the left arrow key in last line. Repeated left arrows movement on the line result in the cursor going to the left THEN back to the end of the same line. It does not move to the last of the previous line (as expected).

2) Up Arrow Key -  When we enter some multiline text in the text field and try to move to the previous line using the Up arrow key. It does not work.

It will be great if somebody can help me on it.

Thanks in Advance :).

Regards

Comment: I really wish I knew the answer to this problem it bugs the hell out of me.  It applies to ie9 & 10.  It's not a line-ending issue and I can reproduce the behavior at specific line indexes - ie the 25th line - regardless of the content - will fail.  I'm currently seeing this behavior on the 7th, 12th and 24th lines for my personal blog.  Left arrow will simply repeat the same line, up arrow will just not respond at these line indexes.  right and down arrows work 100%.  Moving up in mid-sentence will jump to the left-most column of the current row. textarea width has no bearing on line index.

Comment: Changing font-size from inherit to 100% changes the indexes for me by one offset.

Answer (score -1):

I have seen many posts on this in other forums, and had some issues with it in web-based applications we use at my work. It seems to be something weird associated with IE9 and ieSpell.

While some forums have said pressing F7 allows you to get around the problem, it doesn't actually solve it, and there doesn't seem to be any acceptable permanent solution. Some say to dump your browsing history, others to turn caret browsing off in IE options.

Generally, there are lots of suggestions to get around the problem, but none to actually solve it.